# filter in, returning a list of all the dictionaries from the input list which contain the indicated key: value pairing

Tags: python

filterIn
Define a function named filterIn with three parameters.  The first argument passed to the function should be a list of dictionaries (the data), the second a string (a dictionary key), and the third another string (a dictionary value).  This function must return a list of all the dictionaries from the input list which contain the indicated key:value pairing.

How do I go about doing this problem?
This is what I have so far.

```
def filterIn (data, key , x):
  result = []
  for i in data:
    if i == (key, x):
  return (result.append(key, x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```py
def filterIn (data, key , x):
  result = []
  for dictionary in data:
    if dictionary.get(key) == x:
        result.append(dictionary)
  return result

data = [{1:2, 2:2}, {2:2}, {3:1}]
result = filterIn(data, 2, 2)
print(result)

out: [{1: 2, 2: 2}, {2: 2}]
```

" for i in data" will return in the variable 'i' a dictionary, not a key value pair, so you have to then check if the key value pair exists in your dictionary. You can do that by calling 'get' method, which return None if the key is not present in the dictionary. Then you have to append the whole dictionary to the result, not just the key value pair.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Several problems here :

1. When doing `for i in data`, because `data` is a list of dictionaries, `i` is now a dictionary. So, your line `i == (key, x)` has no sense. It should look like :
   `(key, x) in i.items()`, or using the `get` method, with `i.get(key) == x`.
2. You want to return the list of dictionaries that have this pair, so you want to append `i` in your `result` list. So your line `result.append(key, x)` should be `result.append(i)`
3. The `append` indentation is wrong here. You want to append the dictionary if the `if` clause is `True`

So, it should look like something like :

```py
def filterIn(data, key, x):
    result = []
    for i in data:
        if i.get(key) == x:
            result.append(i)
    return i
```

And it can be shortened as :

```py
def filterIn(data, key, x):
    return [i for i in data if i.get(key) == x]
```